# textbox validation for two numbers and two decimal values in asp.net with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, onblur, onkeypress

How to check textbox validation for two numbers and two decimal values in asp.net with javascript?

For Example whien i press the key in textbox it should allow me only xx.xx format, example : 12.25, 25.50,48.45 etc.

Comment: Did you try anything??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" 
         onkeypress="return isDecimalNumber(event,this);" MaxLength="5">
    </asp:TextBox>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  var count = 0;
  function isDecimalNumber(evt, c) {
      count = count + 1;
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
      var dot1 = c.value.indexOf('.');
      var dot2 = c.value.lastIndexOf('.');
      if (count > 2 && dot1 == -1) {
          c.value = "";
          count = 0;
      }
      if (dot1 > 2) {
          c.value = "";
      }
      if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
          return false;
      else if (charCode == 46 && (dot1 == dot2) && dot1 != -1 && dot2 != -1)
          return false;

      return true;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('.TextBox2').keypress(function (event) {
if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

var text = $(this).val();
if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) && (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2)) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/vY39r/

```
$("#amount").on("keyup", function(){
    var valid = /^\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value),
        val = this.value;

    if(!valid){
        console.log("Invalid input!");
        this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate *how* and *why* this solves the OPs answer? While the code may be technically correct, the educational use of it is limited without a single word of explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm new to this community, this page question itself clearly explains what we are discussing about, this script restricts the real number size and it's decimal values, it restricts users to allow only two decimal places after the real value.